# Typescript type string is not assignable to type keyof

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
const KeyboardEventKeys = {
  Escape: 'Escape',
  Enter: 'Enter',
  Tab: 'Tab'
};

type KeyboardEventKeys = keyof (typeof KeyboardEventKeys);

function doSomething(key: KeyboardEventKeys) {}
```

When I'm passing to a function the value of one of the object properties it yells at me:

```
doSomething(KeyboardEventKeys.Enter);
```

One solution is to cast `as KeyboardEventKeys`, but it's a redundant solution. How can I do it without it?

I also don't want to add `doSomething(key: KeyboardEventKeys | string)` because I will lose the type guard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution to use an enum is a good one, and I would recommend you use it.

The reason you get an error is that typescript will not infer string literal types for const members. You can force the compiler to infer string literal types by using an extra function when you create the `const`:

```
function createEnum<T extends { [P in keyof T]: P }>(o: T) {
    return o
}
const KeyboardEventKeys = createEnum({ // typed as { Escape: "Escape"; Enter: "Enter"; Tab: "Tab"; }

    Escape: 'Escape',
    Enter: 'Enter',
    Tab: 'Tab'
});

type KeyboardEventKeys = keyof (typeof KeyboardEventKeys);

function doSomething(key: KeyboardEventKeys) { }
doSomething("Enter")
doSomething("") //err
```

Answer (score 6):

Since [TypeScript 3.4](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) you may force the compiler to preserve literal types by using special `as const` cast construction.
So here you may write

```
const KeyboardEventKeys = {
  Escape: 'Escape',
  Enter: 'Enter',
  Tab: 'Tab'
} as const;

type KeyboardEventKeys = keyof typeof KeyboardEventKeys;

function doSomething(key: KeyboardEventKeys) {}
```

But, ultimately I recommend using `[const] enum KeyboardEventKeys { ... }` instead.

Comment: why do you recommend using enum, when it will generate redundant code

Comment: What particular redundant code will it generate? IIRC it will generate the same `const KeyboardEventKeys` variable, there is no redundancy there

Comment: enum d {A} --> cons d= {0:A,A:0} while i would do d = {A:'A'}

Answer (score 2):

Solution is to use enums instead of objects.

```
enum KeyboardEventKeys {
  Escape ='Escape',
  Enter = 'Enter',
  Tab = 'Tab'
};


function doSomething(key: KeyboardEventKeys) {}
```

You can now pass variables like so

```
doSomething(KeyboardEventKeys.Enter);
```

Comment: This doesn't allow me to pass the raw string doSomething("Enter");

Comment: Also, I don't like enums because they generate more redundant code.

Comment: Why do you have to pass "enter as raw string? You can pass KeyboardEventKeys.Enter instead?

Answer (score 2):

I am posting this here as it matches the thread title.

If you have an object of a Key value pair. You want to loop it with a forEach pulling off the key as a keyof YourObject and the value as a string. (example being input field name and value list) Here is what you need to do.

```js
type FormDataArray = [ keyof FormStateObjectType,  string ];

const entries = Object.entries(state.formData) as FormDataArray[];
entries.forEach(([fieldName, fieldValue]) => {
    // Process code here
});
```

Results in:

- `fieldName` being of type `keyof FormStateObjectType`
- `fieldValue` being of type `string`

Comment: This works, although it is locked to one single value type. By using `Entries` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60142095/23118) you will be able to simply use `const entries = Object.entries(myVar) as Entries<typeof myVar>;` without having to explicitly specifying the object type and it might have members of different types.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
keyof { [key: string]: KeyboarEventKeys }
```

Comment: It works, but you won't get the auto-completion whose inclusion is implied by wanting to use `keyof`