# Typescript Key-Value relation preserving Object.entries type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

The typing for `Object.entries` provided by typescript has the return type `[string, T][]` but I am searching for a generic type `Entries<O>` to represent the return value of this function that keeps the relationship between the keys and the values.

Eg. when having an object type like

```
type Obj = {
    a: number,
    b: string,
    c: number
}
```

I'm looking for a type `Entries<O>` that results in one of the types below (or something similar) when provided with `Obj`:

```
(["a", number] | ["b", string] | ["c", number])[]
[["a", number], ["b", string], ["c", number]]
(["a" | "c", number] | ["b", string])[]
```

---

That this isn't correct for all use cases of Object.entries ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012174/why-doesnt-object-keys-return-a-keyof-type-in-typescript)) is no problem for my specific case.

---

**Tried and failed solution:**

`type Entries<O> = [keyof O, O[keyof O]][]` doesn't work for this as it only preserves the possible keys and values but not the relationship between these as `Entries<Obj>` is `["a" | "b" | "c", number | string]`.

```
type Entry<O, K extends keyof O> = [K, O[K]]
type Entries<O> = Entry<O, keyof O>[]
```

Here the definition of `Entry` works as expected eg. `Entry<Obj, "a">` is `["a", number]` but the application of it in the second line with `keyof O` as the second type variable leads again to the same result as the first try.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Here's a solution, but **beware** when using this as a return type for `Object.entries`; it is not always safe to do that (see below).

---

When you want to pair each key with something dependent on that key's type, use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html):

```js
type Entries<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: [K, T[K]];
}[keyof T][];

type Test = Entries<Obj>;
// (["a", number] | ["b", string] | ["c", number])[]
```

An alternative solution using a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types): this requires `K` to be a "naked type parameter", hence the extra optional generic parameter.

```js
type Entries2<T, K extends keyof T = keyof T> =
    (K extends unknown ? [K, T[K]] : never)[]
```

The second version, which has a tuple type containing the properties instead of a union, is much harder to construct; [it is possible to convert a union to a tuple](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298#issuecomment-468114901) but you basically shouldn't do it.

The third version is manageable, but a bit more complicated than the first version: you need `PickByValue` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55153000/12299000).

```js
type Entries3<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: [keyof PickByValue<T, T[K]>, T[K]]
}[keyof T][];

type Test3 = Entries3<Obj>;
// (["a" | "c", number] | ["b", string])[]
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWyDeAoZQ5OALmRAFcBbdaAbgKPTIGcwpQBzBo5BMyjXp4AvnnF4wATwAOKAKLgOEFgB4AKgD5kAXlyNCAbQDSyUMgDWEKQHsYydQF0yJgDQOTjxwxGGrt+ydDb3FpOQcVMF1kRXZgFVUMTE0GAHpU5AAKQwAiOBz3QVooR2QAH2Rc9ALkNg4QTlKK3IQaouhHAEpgiTCFJXiWACYNd1MIAA9IEAATFktrOwdo-yWtaMzxqYhZ+YoQCxAbAHcQZAB+SuN3dU9SgQgAN2hux1DZFHVIoejY5WHElhNHh0llcvlCtRik1Kjlqu46lwYS02lCOq9eh9kAAFYAICwAISkADU4AAbCgQUbIYnaPS4-HUnBXMxnVaBZweYylSbTOY0i7IUwPZ5QZC+dkORzAyRYv6DADMGjp+l4JlZCwCUpckoZhJJ5Mp1Nu3M0Nzuoj8iw5wQYsvCXzYCt+AxUSqSKRBGWyeRy5WQOVakKEJX9VRqiIaXR6QA)

---

I guess I should also explain why Typescript *doesn't* give a stronger type to `Object.entries`. When you have a type like `type Obj = {a: number, b: string, c: number}`, it's only guaranteed that a value has those properties; it is *not* guaranteed that the value does not also have other properties. For example, the value `{a: 1, b: 'foo', c: 2, d: false}` is assignable to the type `Obj` (excess property checking for object literals aside).

In this case `Object.entries` would return an array containing the element `['d', false]`. The type `Entries<Obj>` says this cannot happen, but in fact it *can* happen; so `Entries<T>` is not a sound return type for `Object.entries` in general. You should only use the above solution with `Object.entries` when you yourself know that the values will have no excess properties; Typescript won't check this for you.

Comment: Well while this may be a true motivation, they easily could have return type as `Entries<T> &  [string, T][]`. It might be not valid TS as I'm not very goot at typelevel, but the idea they could preserve that type T has *at least* these properties and possibly some more (like `d` in your example). It would be then absolutely possible to construct an object from these values and guarantee that it still in valid shape for type T

Comment: is this better than type-fest's [Entries](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest/blob/60a213fff845d44c03923569e503f7f2f3b70d02/source/entries.d.ts#L57)?

Comment: @transang I don't know anything about that library; there is another answer by Peter Cardenas which mentions it but doesn't go into detail.

Comment: @transang yes! type-fest's `Entries` doesn't respect which values go with which keys and ignores length, e.g. `Entries<{name: string, age: number}>` turned into `["name" | "age", string | number][]` for me. That might be sufficient if your objects are homogeneous and length doesn't matter, but I much prefer this answer's result (`(["name", string] | ["age", number])[]`) - doesn't retain length either, but at least it keeps track of the key-value relationships

Comment: @JohnMiller In English, the required type is "an array of ordered pairs [K, V] where K is each key and V is its corresponding value type", which is about as long and unwieldly as the Typescript version, so perhaps we should stop using English too.

Comment: Hi, the first example won't work when the type is a `Partial<>` object as it will return `(['myProp', myValue] | ... | undefined)[]`

Comment: @TOPKAT Yes, it won't; that is a different problem, so you would need to ask a new question about it (but search to see if it already exists first). Particularly you would need to specify what you would want the behaviour to be for a partial type.

Comment: @kaya3 in fact the second solution is working without a problem for Partials, so it may be useful to add it first so it will work in more situations by default ?

Comment: @TOPKAT As I said, you are asking a different question and you haven't specified what you believe should be the correct behaviour for partial types.

Comment: Why is the first example `{ [K in keyof T]: [K, T[K]] }[keyof T][]` and not `{ [K in keyof T]: [K, T[K]] }[]` ?

Comment: @RoboRobok Because that would give you an array of objects, not an array of pairs.

Answer (score 24):

Currently, a really nice utility library called [type-fest](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest) has been introduced to include this functionality for you, among others, in the form of `Entries`. You can use it like so:

```js
import { Entries } from 'type-fest';

Object.entries(obj) as Entries<typeof obj>;
```

Edit: If you want Object.entries to have this type by default:

```js
declare global {
  interface ObjectConstructor {
    entries<T extends object>(o: T): Entries<T>
  }  
}
```

Comment: Yep. And a way to globally set the return type of `Object.entries` is to have a `.d.ts` file with:

`import type { Entries} from 'type-fest'

declare global {
  interface ObjectConstructor {
    entries<T extends object>(o: T): Entries<T>
  }
}`

Comment: @blake.vandercar great point! Might be useful for `Object.fromEntries` add `fromEntries<T extends readonly (readonly [string, unknown])[]>(o: T): {[K in T[number][0]]: Extract<T[number], [K, unknown]>[1]};`

Answer (score 15):

I strongly believe the answer to this post should be a combination of two answers on this page:

```
type Entries<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: [K, T[K]];
}[keyof T][];
```

from *@kaya3*

and

```
const getEntries = <T extends object>(obj: T) => Object.entries(obj) as Entries<T>;
```

from *@minlare*

Thank you both for the excellent answers.

Comment: I would actually add `[K in keyof T]-?: [K, T[K]]` but this is exactly what i use. If you dont have the `-?` then an object using all partial properties would return any as the key values.

Answer (score 8):

```
// utils/objectEntries.ts

export { objectEntries }

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60141960/typescript-key-value-relation-preserving-object-entries-type/75337277#75337277

type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T]
type Entries<T> = [keyof T, ValueOf<T>][]

// Same as `Object.entries()` but with type inference
function objectEntries<T extends object>(obj: T): Entries<T> {
  return Object.entries(obj) as Entries<T>
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Following on from Peter Cardenas answer, I created a helper function as well

```
const getEntries = <T extends object>(obj: T) => Object.entries(obj) as Entries<T>;
```

Answer (score -3):

we can make dedicated function as below:

```
depictObjectKeyType<O>(o: O) {
    return Object.keys(o) as (keyof O)[];
}

depictEntriesKeyType<T>(obj: T): Entries<T> {
    return Object.entries(obj) as any;
}
```

and use as:

```
this.depictEntriesKeyType(data).forEach(....
```

Comment: This answer does not define the `Entries` type as the OP requested, and suggests using `any` to overcome a lack of typing altogether. Using `any` is always the last resort. I don't understand why it has 4 votes...

Comment: Hey @JHH, Thanks you for the suggestion. But, I believe that one should be aware of all the solutions and also for the developers working with TS in initial phase, might need this. Stack-overflow is the perfect place  where we can have solutions from  different  background of developers with various different perspective. Pick what suits your need. Thanks! Have a nice day.

Comment: "Pick what suits your need", the one that doesn't use `any`  

Comment: In this case the `as any` is really not a big deal, as it's only affecting the type returned from `Object.entries` so that it doesn't complain about it not matching `Entries<T>`. The return type of the function is going to replace the `any` anyway. If you really don't like it though, you can easily replace it with `as Entries<T>` instead..