# TypeScript: Mapping object entries to types

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference, typescript-generics

As a novice typescript user, I am having trouble even formulating the question, so please bear with me.

I am trying to create a key => [string + valueObject interface] map of strings and valueObjects (as a type) and then have a function, which enforces the valueObject interface, based on the passed key.

I feel it's best explained by an example:

```
// This is an pseudo example stub, not actually working

type ReplaceableWith<T> = string;
//                   ^ the type I'd like to enforce as the argument

const templates = {
  // templateId    // template               // define somehow the interface required for this template
  'animal.sound': 'A {animal} goes {sound}' as ReplaceableWith<{ animal: string; sound: string}>
};

function renderTemplate(
  templateId , // must be a key of templates
  params // must match value object type, based on templateId
): string {
  let rendered = templates[templateId];
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(params)) {
    // replace keys from template with values
    rendered = rendered.replace('{' + key + '}', value);
  }
  return rendered;
}

const a = renderTemplate('animal.sound', { animal: 'Dog', sound: 'woof' })
//    ^ a = 'A Dog goes woof'
const b = renderTemplate('animal.sound', { name: 'Some' });
//                                         ^ should throw TS error
```

Obviously, this example does not work, but I think it demonstrates what I am trying to acheive. I have made some uneducated attempts with keyof, generics and enums without success.

Is this sort of type mapping (or lookup) even possible?

---

### Update (working example)

After some playing around, here's a working example with a potential solution:

```
type TemplateKeys = {
  'animal.sound': { animal: string; sound: string };
  'animal.sleep': { location: string };
  'animal.herd': { expectedCount: number; available: number };
  'animal.think': undefined;
};

const templates: {[key in keyof TemplateKeys]: string} = {
  'animal.sound': '{animal} goes {sound}',
  'animal.sleep': 'It sleeps in {location}',
  'animal.herd': 'There is {available} animals out of {expectedCount}',
  'animal.think': 'Its thinking'
};

function renderTemplate<K extends keyof TemplateKeys>(key: K, params?: TemplateKeys[K]): string {
  if (params !== undefined) {
    //@ts-ignore
    return Object.entries(params).reduce((previousValue: string, [param, value]: [string, any]) => {
      return previousValue.replace('{' + param + '}', value);
    }, templates[key]);
  }
  return templates[key];
}

console.log(renderTemplate('animal.sound', { animal: 'Dog', sound: 'woof' }));
console.log(renderTemplate('animal.sleep', { location: 'a hut' }));
console.log(renderTemplate('animal.herd', { expectedCount: 20, available: 10 }));
console.log(renderTemplate('animal.think'));
```

Outputs:

```
[LOG]: Dog goes woof 
[LOG]: It sleeps in a hut 
[LOG]: There is 10 animals out of 20 
[LOG]: Its thinking
```

Although this works, it has two issues:

1. I have to define keys twice (in the interface and the instance).
2. The parameters interface and the message are separated, ideally they should be together.

Comment: made an update. Please take a look

Answer (score 1):

**September 17 2021 update**

I have removed any repetitive code.

Also I have created a union of allowed parameters - `Params`. Please see updated example

```js
const enum Animal {
  sound = 'animal.sound',
  sleep = 'animal.sleep',
  herd = 'animal.herd',
  think = 'animal.think',
}

type TemplateKeys = {
  [Animal.sound]: { animal: string; sound: string };
  [Animal.sleep]: { location: string };
  [Animal.herd]: { expectedCount: number; available: number };
  [Animal.think]?: string;
};

const templates = {
  [Animal.sound]: '{animal} goes {sound}',
  [Animal.sleep]: 'It sleeps in {location}',
  [Animal.herd]: 'There is {available} animals out of {expectedCount}',
  [Animal.think]: 'Its thinking'
} as const;

type Templates = typeof templates;

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type Dictionary = {
  [Prop in keyof TemplateKeys]:
  (key: Prop, params: TemplateKeys[Prop]) => string
}

type Params =
  Parameters<
    NonNullable<
      Values<Dictionary>
    >
  >

const renderTemplate = (...params: Params) => {
  const [key, ...props] = params;
  if (props !== undefined) {
    // @ts-ignore
    const result = (Object.entries(props) as Array<Params>)
      .reduce<string>((previousValue, [param, value]) =>
        typeof value === 'string'
          ? previousValue.replace('{' + param + '}', value)
          : previousValue,
        templates[key]
      );

    return result


  }
  return templates[key];
}


renderTemplate(Animal.sleep, { location: 'a hut' }) // ok

renderTemplate(Animal.herd, { expectedCount: 20, available: 10 }) // ok
renderTemplate(Animal.sound, { location: 'sd' }) // expected error
```

I've created `Animal` enum for keys. Don't worry, enum will not be included in your bundle.

Here is the link to  [payground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=3.9.2#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmArgWxgQTAS2QQwDYwDeAsAFAwwQiJgAmMAvDAOQ5a54B0VNtzANGQoQ8cOAAdGLNtnzdREgUJgALOACd6TVuzlrNS8jCgrMYANZSdsribPnDAXzJkoAT3FwYAFTjJxeDhQcADScG4QUiRGANoYNtzUdAC6AFxEMDIc6dDqZgDmANyUSbQ5UHlg+TCOhcpxulwiYuJpGXggwEGY4OWV1bX18Ryc+rRthPAAHp7AwbQAwklQ6UjIAEYaxTgAbjiYgeuiqyib6jV1scNydhbJAPx9BZeDpGSgkLDB-oHBkUzRCgNBI8FLpZiELL4RwwfIgOCRQig2iOQxA65NBStcEASVgzQkkTMRA6XSgPTAqMEV0aow043B3n0XkwiN2+0OohhULwkWosBAADMiHAZnA5nBFssqUNabdzG1mHjIvKCswyNzIh9oJdXB4vL4fkEEVJ3J4hcY-AFjRBdaQzV4AGr4RAIgA83gAfFJvDFzOELd5ki43vb9TAACKYOYUnDqNxReoABXUIEkxP9bkDVt+oXCEDSygAFJn0im0-wYOI4zhkBB0obrcEwhEYuXWgBKRje3IFDUhh0wJM1uuMZTD9S1uDBdQQN3KCgAOXAi8QeE5cHnRgoFGdeFdc6jMfAcbcnoXMHPRiv73A0Bg6gQtA0jdzUiLnE-1cndbLI4gXYMN6gIwNqsB+uElafpw4ipuIBZSN+ta2somDCkWsFppEACEDBMLwcCCmYkpdiBFAAPTkTAAACUAQAAtJg+RgCAj4XmBD4ImusBMEWADy6wAFbilAnAIBUmAIhhcEAZkkRoOok5uG6E7IZ6HYXhQnCPrQiDAJuvZVJ6RbSXAOw9IgEB7q6lYxEhyCVns+5wMkgFXjuHnGPqFpOa6jB4Swhn5Oq26eRQ9xVo+5nUFZLpwNpEiBPpRYQswMAANRViOGUsFSMC+XAGmhWF6SwWZFmxc51JhRQ3xNgiEFuMGxUwB2doeY+UCIOoYCcRA3EhsozhGJ13W9XVuYQI1yQvINpCPnQL45saRYYvILSVpMpLdL00iqIgUBpY4XaUTAIDmCGC3Puor4rWtYybdMszzEsNArDAABMAAMlbsgcOBHHA6QAIxfTUJ1UedZBXUtRrBKttLIo923krtzAQHw4MwKdorPZK8CKaxZBAA)
Here is the link for [Object.entries typings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60141960/typescript-key-value-relation-preserving-object-entries-type)

**Explanation:**

**`Dictionary`** - the main utility type.  It creates an object with `Animal` keys and a function as a value. THis function already takes into account allowed props for particular key.

Example:

```js
type Dictionary = {
    "animal.sound": (key: Animal.sound, params: {
        animal: string;
        sound: string;
    }) => string;
    "animal.sleep": (key: Animal.sleep, params: {
        location: string;
    }) => string;
    "animal.herd": (key: Animal.herd, params: {
        expectedCount: number;
        available: number;
    }) => string;
    "animal.think"?: ((key: Animal.think, params: string | undefined) => string) | undefined;
}
```

Now, we need to convert this data structure to tuple with two elements. First element - a key, second elements - is allowed argument.

You may ask: **Why we need a tuple?** Because `rest` parameters is a tuple.

So we need only to take all values with help of `Values` utility and obtain their parameters with help of `Parameters` built in utility:

```js
type Params =
  | [Animal.sound, {
    animal: string;
    sound: string;
  }]
  | [Animal.sleep, {
    location: string;
  }]
  | [Animal.herd, {
    expectedCount: number;
    available: number;
  }]
  | [Animal.think, string | undefined]

type Params =
  Parameters<
    NonNullable<
      Values<Dictionary>
    >
  >
```