# What is the array/tuple equivalent of 'U in keyof T'?

Tags: typescript

I currently have these types, which works great:

```
type ConfigEntry<T> = {
  value: T;
  option1: boolean;
  option2: number;
  option3: string;
  // ...
};

type Config<T> = Partial<{
  [U in keyof T]: ConfigEntry<T[U]>;
}>;
```

However, in my code I want to be able to loop through the entries of `Config` using `Object.entries()`. The problem is that `Object.entries()` casts the keys to a `string`, so it loses the type safety. Therefore I want to be able to cast them to their corresponding type.

I have tried using the following in a generic class of type T:

```
const entries = Object.entries(configObj) as [keyof T, ConfigEntry<keyof T>][];
```

Unfortunately, this does not ensure that the key (first index) is actually of the same type as the value (second index), but rather any of the value types defined in type T.

How do I solve this in TypeScript?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60141960/typescript-key-value-relation-preserving-object-entries-type)

Comment: Although the answer of this question is equivalent to the suggested answer, the question is different. The answer to my question is (from the suggested answer): `type Entries<T> = { [K in keyof T]: [K, T[K]]; }[keyof T][];`