# Typescript interface type with optional keys of different types

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Here is the data I receive through the API.

```
i_1: {count: 1, name: 'name1', price: 35000}
i_2: {count: 1, name: 'name2', price: 30000}
i_3: {count: 1, name: 'nam3', price: 30000}
```

I defined its type like this.

```
interface Item {
  count: number;
  name: String;
  price: number;
}
```

I added that to a type property called Data.

```
interface Data {
  items?: Item;
 ...etc
}
```

But I ran into a problem when I tried to use Object.entries.

code

```
Object.entries(items).map(([key, value]) => ())
```

The error message is :

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(o: { [s: string]: unknown; } | ArrayLike<unknown>): [string, unknown][]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Item | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ [s: string]: unknown; } | ArrayLike<unknown>'.
      Type 'undefined'enter code here is not assignable`enter code here` to type '{ [s: string]: unknown; } | ArrayLike<unknown>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(o: {}): [string, any][]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Item | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type '{}'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{}'.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is `items?: Item;` meant to just be a single item? It gives the impression it might be intended to contain an array of items.

Comment: Can you update the question to include a [mre], ideally along with a link to your code in the [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/Q) which reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a type which might be undefined to `Object.entries`, to fix this, you can the nullish coalescing operator:

```
Object.entries(items ?? {}).map(([key, value]) => ())
```

Also, TypeScript gives a generic type to `Object.entries`, so if you want to make it use a more precise type, you can either use a cast or refer to the solutions at [Typescript Key-Value relation preserving Object.entries type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60141960/typescript-key-value-relation-preserving-object-entries-type) to make your own `Entries<T>` type for `Object.entries`

Comment: That's... not the problem here. They're passing a potentially undefined value to `Object.entries`.