# Passing (key, value) pairs to addEventListener

Tags: typescript

I have a function that takes an HTMLElement and an object; the object's keys are [event types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) and the values are functions:

```js
function addListeners(el: HTMLElement, listeners: { [key in keyof HTMLElementEventMap]: Function }) {
  if (listeners) {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(listeners)) {
      el.addEventListener(key, value);
    }
  }
}
```

However, Typescript raises these two errors:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(type: keyof HTMLElementEventMap, listener: (this: HTMLElement, ev: Event | ClipboardEvent | UIEvent | AnimationEvent | MouseEvent | ... 13 more ... | WheelEvent) => any, options?: boolean | ... 1 more ... | undefined): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof HTMLElementEventMap'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions | undefined): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Function' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventListenerOrEventListenerObject'.
```

Comment: Because [TS is structural](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) objects with excess properties can be used in any place as long as the required keys and values exist. e.g. https://tsplay.dev/WYLDbm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript Key-Value relation preserving Object.entries type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60141960/typescript-key-value-relation-preserving-object-entries-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the type information of `key` will be lost after `Object.entries` and turns into `string`.

By taking the reference from [this post](https://effectivetypescript.com/2020/05/26/iterate-objects/) of keeping the type of the keys while looping an object, here is a workaround that declare the type of key before the loop.

```
function addListeners(el: HTMLElement, listeners: { [key in keyof HTMLElementEventMap]: Function }) {
  if (listeners) {
    let key: keyof typeof listeners;
    for (key in listeners) {
      el.addEventListener(key, listeners[key]);
    }
  }
}
```

After that, it is complaining type `Function` in incompatible to argument of `addEventListener`.

To fix this, you can inspect the [typescript dom definition](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/src/lib/dom.generated.d.ts#L7011), and modify the type of `listeners`. Which can also strengthen the type guard of `listeners` (prevent mismatch of key and callback, auto-infering the type of `event`).

Also, `{ [key in keyof HTMLElementEventMap]: Function }` will enforce you to implement all members of `HTMLElementEventMap`. To make it optional, surround it with [`Partial<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype)

Here is a full solution in [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.0-dev.20230111#code/C4TwDgpgBAMglgZ2BAdhATgHgNJQgD2RQBMEoBrCEAewDMoAJAFQFkYBRAGwgFtVh2AN34sAhmAB8UALxQAFMAAWiAFyNWHbnxTAANHkFrmbLr35CR4gNrYAugEoZU0ShAAoN7QCuKAMbA4ahQoUWJieCRUDAQ5CE4jDVNtPShORCJotQAFUXQA0U5MAG8oK0oQKDhg8rp1Ey1zYR0xMFs1CIyscqkAXwlHIrcoSvo5NMi0dAQBoeHUiGAKKjUa+lBIWvHOhABuWeHaanR5csrgraipmbm5gHpb4YA9AH59ud8gpFT0y5lvieiZSothCZA6l0w6wgtW6exuw3uNxeb2GcQAdKFiBYdODJnJyvoLpN7HC5j1ZuTyW5EaIvMBqGdaBh0FUAOZQQ6+LxkCBNYBuTG46JyIo9UEhVz6QYHahchBqWKCRzSKTS96fRa8-h-XmkhEPObI4aU+weRHMo5QADuilQoIQcFZKDZISgPGo3OgF2O9I5su5Bn4bg+KC+7s9QuOskVahYHoQEGxwGVqp6e0FP0mMVF4pcICls053LU4YTkbcPXsQA)

Answer (score 0):

There are two overload for `addEventListener`
first one take first arg as `key of HTMLElementEventMap`  and second arg as a function that will take `Event |UIEvent | ...13 more` as param and return any if you want to use that one then change your code to

```
function addListeners(el: HTMLElement, listeners: { [key in keyof HTMLElementEventMap]: (e:Event | UIEvent)=> any }) {
  //you can add other types as well after UIEvent
  if (listeners) {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(listeners)) {
      el.addEventListener(key, value);
    }
  }
}
```

Second one take first arg as `string` and the second arg as `EventListenerOrEventListenerObject` if you want to use this one
then change your code to

```
function addListeners(el: HTMLElement, listeners: { [key in keyof HTMLElementEventMap]: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject}) {
  if (listeners) {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(listeners)) {
      el.addEventListener(key, value);
    }
  }
}
```

[image]