# Typescript errors while destructuring foreach from object.entries output

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am having certain types that are categorized based on mimetypes

```
export type MimeType = 'image' | 'application' | 'text';

export type ApplicationMimeType = '.pdf' | '.zip';

export type ImageMimeType = '.gif' | '.png' | '.jpeg' | '.jpg' | '.svg' ;

export type TextType = '.csv' | '.txt';

export type ExtensionTypes = ImageMimeType[] | ApplicationMimeType[] | TextType[];

export type FileType = {
  image?: ImageMimeType[];
  application? : ApplicationMimeType[];
  text? : TextType[]
};
```

Now when I use it in a function, then use Object.entries when a certain object is passed, the key type is set to string. Is there a way for this key to be set to the type of MimeType?

I tried the solution that is given in this link: [Typescript Key-Value relation preserving Object.entries type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60141960/typescript-key-value-relation-preserving-object-entries-type)

Code I tried that is giving me error `Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string[]'`.

How can I restrict key to be `MimeType` and extensions to be `ExtensionTypes`

```
export type Entries<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: [extensions: T[K]][];
}[keyof T][];

export const getAcceptedFileTypes = (mimeTypes: FileType) => {
  const acceptedTypes = {};
  Object.entries(mimeTypes as Entries<mimeTypes>).forEach(([key, extensions]) => {
    if (key === 'text') {
      acceptedTypes['text/*'] = extensions;
    } else if (key === 'image') {
      extensions.forEach(
        (image) => (acceptedTypes[`image/${image.substring(1)}`] = [image])
      );
    } else {
      extensions.forEach(
        (application) =>
          (acceptedTypes[`application/${application.substring(1)}`] = [
            application,
          ])
      );
    }
  });
  return acceptedTypes;
};

getAcceptedFileTypes({ image: ['.png'], application: [] })
```

tsconfig

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
  },
  "files": [],
  "include": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.lib.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./.storybook/tsconfig.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: getAcceptedFileTypes = <T extends FileType>(mimeTypes: T) in optional using should be work in your case

Comment: @akkasumeyye
 that still gives me key type as string

Comment: can you try with the following `Entries` and see if it works with your tsconfig?
`export type Entries<T> = {[K in keyof T]: [key: K, extensions: T[K]];}[keyof T][];`

Comment: @wonderflame How should this Entries type  be used in the function?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include that. Please, try the following. `(Object.entries(mimeTypes) as Entries<FileType>).forEach(`

Comment: @wonderflame , it throws me this `Type '[key: "image", extensions: ImageMimeType[] | undefined] | [key: "application", extensions: ApplicationMimeType[] | undefined] | [key: "text", extensions: TextType[] | undefined] | undefined' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator`

Comment: I suspect this is because of your specific `tsconfig`, for me there are no errors. could you share your config so I can adjust to your case?

Comment: @wonderflame added the same to the question

Comment: Can you try [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wXv5Vm)? Also, make sure that the file in which you are using this code is added in `tsconfig.include`

Comment: @wonderflame, worked like a charm, please add this as an answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript Key-Value relation preserving Object.entries type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60141960/typescript-key-value-relation-preserving-object-entries-type)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative to the solution provided by @Teneff, instead of extending the entries type, you should first redeclare the `Entries` with the following:

```
export type Entries<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: [K, T[K]];
}[keyof T][];
```

Also, you should change the way you do the type assertion as follows.

```
(Object.entries(mimeTypes) as Entries<FileType>)
```

[playground](https://tsplay.dev/wXv5Vm)

Answer (score 0):

You can use TypeScript's [Declaration Merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to add an overload to `Object.entries` like this

```js
declare global {
    interface ObjectConstructor {
        entries<T>(o: T): Entries<T>;
    }
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCyBLAtsAKs1AXjgHJsBDAc2BLgB9TywwAbDAY3JgwgDtaGJGKBgkA3AFgAUNNCRYCAnACCzNp259MOfCjjESAOjAATAGYDShgF4Yw46bPDR4SPQEksVYNrxKDhpQYFvRWYLyUlkYAViiRoTFg8YKGAM4AbpGSMlJyLop6uCK6RFbsGVGGMCCi2U7yrkoAojXAvKk8vCWp+nCe3r4lANoAuqGqrBxcnYMEo6FFNcMjdVJuqE28MFAYwKkAPLgAfL24cCJtJj0A3gC+0nCPcAD8cAAU1w9P30MA0nAYXhwADWwEQEDMcFwIwAXHA-gAaOAAJWAAEcAK4YKDAEyHI5-EYjL6PW5DUHgyHQgCUoxJcDhvGA6WAUEcUhMwHYLHIOLglBYEAARuQWHBPlJvoDhFAzOR2KgAPJC6JcmAAYT4qW2GPYMGg4vp3za212B2ObwgcNw1Lhm1Ne3x2W+9ykrryCnWcAAYhgWH49MQJVKvNQ4f1qLMUKNsrd6NJg08mJMNJ04RN1NMtNgA8AY9I43QE-ThDVrcU5sS3eyPfB2Fr4NQYMp2AqwMITL7-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-VzIcvpKXo7mkYa4vU8anzeGAbruh6nte97Pu7AhqSAA)

---

**TL;DR**

You can define your `Entries` like this:

```
type Entries<T> = T extends {}
    ? Array<{
        [K in keyof T]: [K, Required<T>[K]]
    }[keyof T]
    >
    : never
```

and you'll notice that `Entries<FileType>` also includes `undefined`

```
 [
  | "image", ImageMimeType[]][]
  | ["application", ApplicationMimeType[]][]
  | ["text", TextType[] 
  | undefined
  // ^ here
 ][]
```

that's because the way `FileType` is defined

```
const thisIsAlsoAValidFileType: FileType = {}
```

what you probably need is an union type like this:

```
type FileType = {
    image: ImageMimeType[];
} |
{
    application: ApplicationMimeType[];
} |
{
    text: TextType[]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check in [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCyBLAtsAKs1AXjgHJsBDAc2BLgB9TywwAbDAY3JgwgDtaGJGKBgkA3ACgJoSLAQE4AQWZtO3Pphz4UcYiQB0YACYAzAaX0AvDGHFSZ0eEh0BJLFWCa8CvfsoYzegswXkpzAwArFDCgyLAYwX0AZwA3GMlpcEd5HVwRbSILdlTw-RgQUQyHOWdUAFEK4F4knl4CpN04Nw8vAoBtAF0g5VYOLlbegkGgvIr%20gaqsmoUAMQwWbx1iAG8JODgKagB%20AC4u92pJlEHJfaZRtVajuDOR1XGNbE3gG72EEWeZ1mMHmEgAvhlMrInAo6rwYFAMMAkgAeXAAPl0u32fQA0gdeHAANbARAQExwABKwAAjgBXDBQYBGNHogZnPEAGmp9MZzNZeIGA0G4L6JLJFJ5DKZLIxAykAHoFXA4Qikai1hsCuiJEq4H0AESHYAGznnHpfebCoYMQ33d7qXimpQqMaOq4-IXTW0G4QVZ3Aq0iqHZWpU4AwOlQNo%20bH6-EYQni8nh3kylGa75ss5SvkszPawUisH2Jbwdh8JLwagwRTsdjAMDCIwFggdYgACiwlrbZ1bKAAlLpMXGK814OR643m%200c8AK1AWVXEaEzcvE5RBpidhC-h2APIAIwi85g%20iaauRXZ7KCSQ-IHVViORGfWWYH%20hM0Dqk4AFh2OzFUkzREJoWkrAYh0IEc-n2AI4A7cVdEIPQ-VEIc432O4pybZl2j6IQRAVAAqEghmIUDmlaJJbiwsE4GAFgklQeDENJZC9GNEgMNgrDKPA5pP2-P8O14rCEONKDMQ7ScG1wox8IAA2NBUABJtmNZI6UPddQg7ABGAcwUU8j9WNSCxLgAdaP2ejGOYuBML4xoqMrISoB-dh-0s-YZNdR4%20CknysJknCZzbPpFPtN1WjU7ZooC3gtJ0tU9MM4zTL6YLxISj5eE5bK4As8T9ms3iS1ssr9iZSNozgWTpzwttJF3CQazrOTm37K9tgOC5gA5AwQjCTk4mAMIBjNXLHUGwxTDIuAwQHIA)

````
export type ApplicationMimeType = '.pdf' | '.zip';

export type ImageMimeType = '.gif' | '.png' | '.jpeg' | '.jpg' | '.svg' ;

export type TextType = '.csv' | '.txt';

export type ExtensionTypes = ImageMimeType[] | ApplicationMimeType[] | TextType[];

export type FileType = {
  image?: ImageMimeType[];
  application? : ApplicationMimeType[];
  text? : TextType[]
};


export type Entries<T> ={
  [K in keyof Required<T>]: [K,Required<T>[K]][]
}[keyof Required<T>]

// Entries<FileType>
// ["image", ImageMimeType[]][] | ["application", ApplicationMimeType[]][] | ["text", TextType[]][]

export type ReturnType ={
  [K in keyof Required<FileType>]: Required<FileType>[K][]
}

export const getAcceptedFileTypes = (mimeTypes: FileType) => {
  const acceptedTypes: Record<string, string[]> = {};
  (Object.entries(mimeTypes) as Entries<FileType>).forEach(([key, extensions]) => {
    if (key === 'text') {
      acceptedTypes['text/*'] = extensions;
    } else if (key === 'image') {
      extensions.forEach(
        (image) => (acceptedTypes[`image/${image.substring(1)}`] = [image])
      );
    } else {
      extensions.forEach(
        (application) =>
          (acceptedTypes[`application/${application.substring(1)}`] = [
            application,
          ])
      );
    }
  });
  return acceptedTypes;
};

getAcceptedFileTypes({ image: ['.png','.jpeg'], application: ['.pdf'] })```
````