# Dynamically get keys of function parameter for the return values in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have the following function:

```ts
function doSomething(data: { [key: string]: [number, number] }, height: number): { matchingData: string | undefined } {
  for (const [key, [min, max]] of Object.entries(data)) {
    if (height >= min && height < max) {
      return { matchingData: key };
    }
  }

  return { matchingData: undefined };
}
```

For the return value `matchingData` of the function, I want to have a string union of the keys of `[key: string]`. So when I use the function I have syntax completion for the `matchingData` like this:

```ts
const data = doSomething({ small: [0, 50], medium: [50, 100], large: [100, 150] }, 42);
if (data.matchingData === "small") {
  console.log("no syntax completion");
}

if (data.matchingData as "small" | "medium" | "large" === "small") {
  console.log("has syntax completion");
}
```

I tried different stuff like keyof, but so far I did not manage to handle it. If it's not solvable, maybe there's a better input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a generic parameter to have TypeScript infer the keys of the parameter and then use that in the return type:

```
function doSomething<Keys extends string>(data: Record<Keys, [number, number]>, height: number): { matchingData: Keys | undefined } {
```

However, this causes problems later on in `Object.entries` (see [Typescript Key-Value relation preserving Object.entries type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60141960/typescript-key-value-relation-preserving-object-entries-type)), so we have to add an assertion there:

```
for (const [key, [min, max]] of Object.entries(data) as [Keys, [number, number]][]) {
```

With these changes, you will now get suggestions here:

```
if (data.matchingData === "") {
    //                     ^ prompt for suggestions here
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: Thanks. That would help. My problem is that my real implementation of doSomething already has generic parameters and I cannot partially infer generic parameters.

Comment: @julian.a that sounds like a followup question and shouldn't prevent you from accepting this answer.  Or, I suppose you could edit your question to specify that you can't use generics, but then the question might be overconstrained and the answer is "you can't do this" (although partial generic type argument inference is quite often worked around with currying).