# How to get Rid of Typescript Type error in the IDE regarding object properties

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio, mobx, mobx-react

**Background**

I created a custom hook using React and MobX.

The custom hook receives an object `units` of type `StoreUnits` and also contains a `useState` hook that holds an object `currentUnits` of type `StoreUnits`.

Inside the custom hook I am iterating the over the object `units`, and if one of its properties is different than `currentUnits` im using the useState setter to update `currentUnits`.

**The problem**

I get a type error (**in the IDE alone, not in run time**) on the `currentUnits[key]` and `units[key]`
even though I specified for both `units` and `currentUnits` are of type `StoreUnits`.

**The Error**

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'StoreUnits'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'StoreUnits'.ts(7053)
const currentUnits: StoreUnits
```

**The code - custom hook**

```
'use client'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { autorun } from 'mobx'

type StoreUnits = {
  lengthUnit: 0 | 1 | 2 | 3
  pointForceUnit: 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8
  stressUnit: 0 | 1 | 2 | 3
  areaUnit: 0 | 1 | 2
}

const useCurrentUnits = (units: StoreUnits) => {
    const [currentUnits, setCurrentUnits] = useState<StoreUnits>(units)
    
    useEffect(() => {
      autorun(() => {
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(units)) {
          if (currentUnits[key] !== units[key]) {
            setCurrentUnits({...units})
            break
          }
        }
      })
    }, [units])
  return {
    currentUnits
  }
}

export default useCurrentUnits
```

**What I tried**

I can specify something like `currentUnits[key as 'lengthUnit']` and then the error will disappear, but it doesn't feel right because the key is not always 'lengthUnit'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with how `Object.entries` is currently typed (see [Typescript Key-Value relation preserving Object.entries type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60141960/typescript-key-value-relation-preserving-object-entries-type)). Right now, it will always return `string` as the type of the keys. Now, I'm not going to go in on why this is the case - there's already many explanations out there already - but to solve this problem, you'll need an assertion.

There are other ways to get around this, but this is the easiest.

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(units) as [keyof StoreUnits, number][]) {
//                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMDKMCGN0A0KGAogGZnoDG8AvnGVBCHAORTo42sCwAUKEixEcHMhjRkAOzj1GzNiAgAjAB68+-GAE8w6ONmjoAqlOAxUcALyJ+cOABt0UgOYwAFqfMAuOAAY4AB84AEYguAAmcIBmOzhIYCkYADFoKhMzGF8A4LDgqODo8IAWcIBWcIA2cIB2cIAOONQYDlRULyz-cLzImLicDhwO7O7wiP5afn4qCClm4nQAYWQoDiSOyxsACmlzVF9DDg2ASmsAPls+e3sZufgAbSoVtZgNogwYZdXnV8zUAF1rAtsHh0AAeQ4ZPZnHZ-Y5xewIhbkSg0LZbU5WC4IJH2MQSKDSdGY7G465kaBwLa3eb3ADW6G0RAAbjgHMh0ICIGQ4AB5ZQAK2oMAAdD8oMB0KhYXtTjhLPTGdyDASoRYiFJkCBlOgoP97v9TjirtdTfZgDzqc8fhtFdpAQBCKw2XYWO2Gy5mr1wD5fF4bLYIEXB12oWjwk3e67KQZ0smmyaRs2Jr3hpG0Ij3UOGuIcGArGTG01Pb7rP5xROJ-joVRCeAAE3QZDEDngaCW1rLeyAA)

---

I do notice that you aren't even using the value (yet, at least), so in that case, you could just use `Object.keys`. This still needs the assertion though.

Parentheses are important because of operator precedence here.

```
for (const key of Object.keys(units) as (keyof StoreUnits)[]) {
//                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMDKMCGN0A0KGAogGZnoDG8AvnGVBCHAORTo42sCwAUKEixEcHMhjRkAOzj1GzNiAgAjAB68+-GAE8w6ONmjoAqlOAxUcALyJ+cOABt0UgOYwAFqfMAuOAAY4AB84AEYguAAmcIBmOzhIYCkYADFoKhMzGF8A4LDgqODo8IAWcIBWcIA2cIB2cIAOONQYDlRULyz-cLzImLicDhwO7O7wiP5afn4qCClm4nQAYWQoDiSOyxsACmlzVF9DDg2ASmsAPls+e3sZufgAbSoVtZgNogwYZdXnV8zUAF1rAtsHh0AAeQ4ZPZnHZ-Y5xewIhbkSg0LZbU5WC4IJH2MQSKDSdGY7G465kaBwLa3eYAa3Q2jgEDIcAA8soAFbUGAAOnp2lQsL2pxwli2-OZBgJUIsx3u-1OOKu1xV9mALOpzx+G3u-MBAEIrDZdhZdQyFZdVVa4B8vi8NlsEDznSbULR4crrddlINaWSVZNParA1b3UjaER7q6FXEODAVjIlSqnt91n84oHA-x0KohPAACboMhiBzwNBLLVpvZAA)